# Oracle Reports: Can I Use Multiple Image According to Query in One Report?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I want to use 4 different images according to where statement of my query. Is it possible in Oracle Reports?

Comment: Is it possible? Probably. How? No idea. It would help if you described what exactly you think. A screenshot might help.

Comment: I have 4 images and one table "table_a" and its column "column_a". I want that if column_a = 1, the report shows image 1, if column_a = 2, it shows image 2 etc...

Comment: Looks like CASE (or DECODE).

Comment: So? How can I show (insert) different images in case statement?

Comment: you use a formula column, and use the CASE to return the image file name. eg. 
 return CASE when :column_a = 1 then 'c:\dir\image1.jpg' when :column_a = 2 then 'c:\dir\image2.jpg' ...else 'c:\dir\default.jpg' end; then set the properties of the field read from file = yes and file format=image

Comment: I used formula column but I got an error. I searched some and didn't find the solution. This is my new question about it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340337/oracle-reports-a-read-only-bind-variable-used-in-out-or-in-out-context

Comment: Formula column worked! Thank you @MichaelBroughton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used formula column (in comment of @MichaelBroughton).

1. I added a formula column to my Data Model.
2. In property of column I choose Datatype = Character, Read from File = Yes and File Format = Image
3. This is PL/SQL Formula:

> ```
> function CF_1Formula return Char is
> begin
>     null;
>     if :column_a  = 1 then
>       return 'c:\dir\image1.jpg';
>     elsif :column_a  = 2 then 
>       return 'c:\dir\image2.jpg';     
>   end if; 
> end;
> ```