# Oracle Reports A READ-ONLY bind variable used in OUT or IN-OUT context

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, report, oraclereports

I have a formula column in my report as you can see in the image. When I compile it, I have an error: "A READ-ONLY bind variable used in OUT or IN-OUT context"

My query gets 1 line result. Properties like in the image. Why I got this error and what is the solution?

[image: Image:]

Comment: So when you call your function what do you use as `:cf_1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function code is wrong (obviously; Oracle told you so). Should be something like this:

```
function CF_1Formula return char is
begin
  return case when :kart_geldimi = 'E' then 'sss'
              else null
         end;
end;
```

Basically, you created something like a circular reference and tried to use formula column as the `OUT` value (that's what `:cf_1 := 'sss';` did).